# Ошибка CharFields must define a 'max_length' attribute

Tags: python, django

При запуске runserver выдает ошибку:

> articles.Article.article_title: (fields.E120) CharFields must define a 'max_length' attribute.

Ошибка в файле models.py, так как, когда я удалил содержимое файла,то все работало без ошибок!
Вот код файла:

```
from django.db import models  
import datetime 
from django.utils import timezone

#Статьи
class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField("название статьи")
    article_text = models.TextField("текст статьи")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("дата публикации")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title
    
    def date(self):
        return self.pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 7)) 
    

#Комменты к статьям 
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField("имя автора ", max_length = 50)
    comment_text = models.CharField("текст комментария", max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name
```

Comment: Спасибо!Все работает!

Answer (score 1):

Для полей типа `CharField` нужно обязательно указать `max_length` - максимальную длину.
Вы забыли сделать это для поля `article_title`. Нужно сделать так:

```
article_title = models.CharField("название статьи", max_length=50)
```